# What is the height of the header in DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

What is the height of the header in DrawerLayout?

[image]

The problem is that the content comes over the top menu. I have to add padding `android: layout_marginTop = "80dp"` for content. And yet, what a universal unit of measurement should I choose?

```
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerMainActivity);
```

`XML` - structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerMainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerView">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            />
    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: apply android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"

Answer (score 0):

Use style:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">30dp</item>
</style>
```

And add to manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/CastomTheme" >
 </activity
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this. Use linearlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerMainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <Linearlayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            />

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerView">

     </FrameLayout>
 </Linearlayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I recommend this solution

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

you can use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize" //change here
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        />
```

Now you can use the padding Top attribute as:

```
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

**Method 2**

you can find the `actionbar` height in runtime in pixel and set padding to your view accordingly

```
    // Calculate ActionBar's height 
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue(); 
if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
    actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
}
```

now you can set `padding Top` programetically using:

```
view.setPadding(0, actionBarHeight ,0,0);  // 2nd param - Top
```

As i understand if your fragment container overlapse with `toolbar`:

you should use this layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/top_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerMainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/containerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/background_color" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now u can replace content frame without `toolbar` overlapping